# Import module to gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've cloned the volley library to `/Users/user/volley`

How can I import it as a module to my android studio project, powered with gradle, similar to "Import module" option in IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513272/android-studio-volley

Comment: possible duplicate of [Volley Android Networking Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16659620/volley-android-networking-library)

Comment: The thing is that I want to import the module, not the jar. And the new Android Studio is missing File -> Import module.

Comment: To use volley as a dependency module, you can follow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23402162/1093344)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And the new Android Studio is missing File -> Import module.

That is because AndroidStudio has nothing to do with your build anymore. Gradle is the one, who is actually building your application. And if you want to add volley to your project you have to edit `build.gradle` script. There are links at the comments or you can use next one as a snippet:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android:volley:1.0'
}
```

After you added those lines, press `Sync project with gradle files` and AndroidStudio will import your module.

Comment: This site is helpful http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ to find dependencies names. But it works only if author update his library and upload its @aar to mavenCentral repository. For those libraries which dont we have community. Check the whole list here: https://github.com/Goddchen/mvn-repo/

Comment: And what to do if I have a library as a independent project, even not a jar? In the earlier versions I was able to connect this projects with "Import module"

Comment: Thoose are libraries at `gradleplease`, like facebookSDK or actionBarSherlock. Just add dependency line. That's it. Gradle will download, import, etc. it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Now the dependency is like that:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
}
```