# Project Structure Dialogue in Android Studio 0.5.3 not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently installed Android Studio 0.5.3 but the project structure window isn't showing correctly. Below is a screenshot.

[image: Project Structure Dialogue]

I'm sure it should have more options down the side, but if I click on Modules then the + button, I don't get any import option, only another dialogue to actually create a new library project.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Check the version - 0.5.3 :) Not all the features are implemented at the moment.

Comment: It is supposed to be there according to the release notes and I definetely have 0.5.3

Comment: It stated over here. http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio053released I can't find the option on 0.5.3.

Comment: It has to do with incorrect setup of your gradle project. Once your project is structured correctly, it might give you more options.

Try this plugin if you're having problems with setting up gradle based project. https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin

Comment: Did you find what was causing this? Had any luck finding a soultion?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I spent ages trying to figure it out but no joy. I've ended up going back to Eclipse as found Android Studio to be still a bit too buggy.