# Gradle project refresh failed compile error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Getting gradle sync error

> Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :volley.

what does it mean? I guess I need to add something to build.gradle file?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513272/android-studio-volley

Comment: Post your settings.gradle and build.gradle files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding Following dependencies to your app's build.gradle :

```js
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```